# Counter with repeated states

Tags: counter, verilog

I'm quite familiar with making a counter in Verilog by defining states (the count) and transitioning between states.

For example, making a counter that counts 0,1...,9 and back to 0.

However, I'm not too sure how I would implement it if say the count went like 1,2,3,3,3,4,0 then back to 1.

Could anyone give me some ideas on how I could implement this?

Answer (score 1):

In your counter example you have a FSM (Finite State Machine) where the output is the state. One approach to your question is to consider this as an FSM where this is not true and you add a decode between state and output.

```
logic [2:0] state;
logic [2:0] value;

always @(posedge clk, negedge rst_n) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    state <= 'b0;
  end
  else begin
    if (state >= 3'd6) begin
      //reset state when get to max as non-power of 2 states
      state <= 'b0;
    end
    else begin
      state <= state +1;
  end
end

always @* begin
  case (state)
    3'd0 : value ='d1;
    3'd1 : value ='d2;
    3'd2 : value ='d3;
    3'd3 : value ='d3;
    3'd4 : value ='d3;
    3'd5 : value ='d4;
    3'd6 : value ='d0;

    default: value ='d0;
  endcase
end
```

Comment: The output sequence in your code after reset is 0,1,2,3,3,3,4,0,0,1,... which is slightly different that what OP asked.

Comment: @ari your correct but given that this is not a code writing service, I think this gives the OP enough of hint on how to implement what they want.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a counter, you can **reuse** it. It is recommended to use generic modules that you have already tested.

I will assume that your counter has the following interface:

```
counter (
input rst,
input clk,
ouput [2:0] count
);
```

using this counter you can get the value you want by:

```
module your_module (
input rst,
input clk,
ouptut [2:0] value
);

wire [2:0] count;

counter counter ( // creating a counter from 0 to 6
.rst (rst)
.clk (clk)
.count (count)
);

always (*) begin  // converting 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 into 1,2,3,3,3,4,0
  case (count)
    3'd0 : value = 3'd1;
    3'd1 : value = 3'd2;
    3'd2 : value = 3'd3;
    3'd3 : value = 3'd3;
    3'd4 : value = 3'd3;
    3'd5 : value = 3'd4;
    3'd6 : value = 3'd0;
    default : value = 3'bxxx; // just to make sure no other state
  endcase
end

endmodule;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can optimize counter to value mapping, consider replacement "case" section from Morgan's code to something like this:

value <= cnt[2] ? ( cnt[1] ? 4 : 3 ) : cnt;

But it's less readable, so bad idea until this part is multiplied and you in lack of gates.